# submitting login information to Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, submit

once again I'm stuck with my code.
I am trying to write a simple login. 
The Website with the login is generated by a servlet and once the Login information is inserted, it should be send back to it.
This works fine, if I execute it directly in Eclipse, but if try to access the program in a browser, absolutely nothing happens. I click on the Login button and it is not happening anything at all. I suppose, there is a missing link somewhere halfway from the Website to the Servlet, but I can't figure out where.

The servlet is called "Main.java" and is executed on a tomcat Server
This is the code in doGet() where the login is generated:

```
String s="<h1>Welcome</h1><p><form action=\"Main\" method=\"post\"></p><p>User: <input type=\"text\" name=\"user\"><br></p><p>Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"pass\"><br></p><p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\"</form></p>";
```

This is the code for doPost() where the input should be taken:

```
    PrintWriter writer= response.getWriter();
    String user=request.getParameter("user");
    String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
    System.out.println(user);
    System.out.println(pass);
    String dbuser="asdf";
    String dbpass="asd";
    if (user.equals(dbuser) && pass.equals(dbpass)){
        writer.println("<html><head></head><body>Logged in! <br>" + user + "<br>" + pass);
    } else{
        writer.println("<html><head></head><body>Wrong Login! <br>" + user + "<br>" + pass);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is missing a closing bracket on the Login input.
Should be:

```
String s="<h1>Welcome</h1><p><form action=\"Main\" method=\"post\"></p>   <p>User: <input type=\"text\" name=\"user\"><br></p><p>Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"pass\"><br></p><p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\"></form></p>";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I never thought about an error in that String, because eclipse was somehow able to execute the program.

Comment: Not sure if you care, but you also have invalid tag nesting. Run your doGet html through an html validator.